# Creating a representative sample

Tags: sampling, representative

I'd like to create a representative sample from a larger population for monitoring (a hold-out control).  I've thought of three approaches and am trying to select between them (plus I'm open to others):

1. Simply to take a random sample.
2. Perform a distribution test on the sample and reject/repeat if it is too different
3. Produce many samples and score them all based on how similar the distributions are.  Go with the closest

For example the population's average spend is ~\$60, it's not normally distributed but for simplicity I'll say the SD is ~\$100.  If I take a sample of 100 people then most of the time I'll have the mean of the sample between \$54 and \$66.  If the sample's mean is say \$54 or less then I'm worried it's just a bit too different to the population.

I can solve that by picking a bigger sample.  1000 people would make it $\pm 2$ rather than $\pm 6$, but it also means I'm holding 1000 people out and people generally don't like to be part of the hold-out control.  Can I instead solve it by calculating the sample's basic stats, rejecting and rerolling the sample if it fails?  Or will this introduce other problems?

Comment: You might do better to rank the population by spending, split that into groups and sample the desired proportion from each group so that all individuals have the same probability of being sampled; if you had a million people and wanted a sample of 100, you could make each group 10,000 in size and take one from each group.  (Since the individual from the highest spending group might not be typical, this is not the best way to find the mean - for that you could oversample the highest spending group, but that is a different question).  If it matters, you could stratify by other factors

Comment: The subtle pitfalls in (2) and (3) would likely make them useless for many purposes.  Instead, think about options for random sampling.  You don't have to settle for simple random sampling.  You can use stratified sampling, probability samples, cluster samples, adaptive samples, *etc.,* depending on how you structure the population, its statistical characteristics, and your monitoring needs.  You haven't offered enough information to suggest any definite solution.